# Creating Cron Job on cPanel for Task Scheduling in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel, laravel-8

Pretty much the title. I am doing it as it says in the docs but it won't work. No log updates in laravel.log file either which might have helped. This is how I set up my cron job:

[image]

I also gave it my mail address where it should send the log of the job and it sometimes does do that but sometimes doesn't which I didn't quite understand why. Anyway, the mail content was simply what Laravel says when you type `php artisan` in the terminal. Like it shows you all the commands of Laravel.

Any idea why it doesn't work and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to change the line of command to this:

```
   /usr/local/bin/php /home/cpanel-user/laravel-app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```